# How can I declare a date where the day or month are unknown?

Tags: javascript, date, neo4j

Coming from PHP and MySQL I've taken a liking to the ability to store dates where the day or month is unknown. 
Say I have this (presuming the NO_ZERO_IN_DATE sql mode is off):

```sql
CREATE TABLE norwegianKings(id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255), bornDate DATE);
INSERT INTO norwegianKings(name, bornDate) VALUES('Magnus the Good', '1024-00-00');
INSERT INTO norwegianKings(name, bornDate) VALUES('Harald V', '1937-02-21');
```

Then it will handle both a king with known birth day, month, and year, and one where only the year is known. Ordering by bornDate will work, and when I need to output it I can just strip away any "-00" parts. This is because the PHP variable holding bornDate would be a string.

In my new project I am instead using JavaScript and a Neo4j database. Neither of them, as far as I know, has the same ability to handle imprecise dates.
Doing

```js
const date = new Date("1024");
console.log(date);
```

will just give me "1024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", which is no good, as I won't be able to know if this king was born on an unknown day in 1024 or on the 1st of January 1024.

So what would be a good strategy here?

Suggestions:

1. Having bornDate as a Date, while also having bornYear as a string
   which I use when printing?
2. Let bornDate be a string. Will this affect ordering?
3. Having a flag 'impreciseDate'. When it is set to true I'll strip away the "-01" parts

Comment: Dates in JS are annoying as hell. They're based on 1970 or 1900 and also on UTC/GMT position of the person running the code. For example, I'm in the USA, East Coast, so if I want to store the year 1024 *only* as a date, I actually need to write `const date = new Date(Date.UTC(1024)); const year = date.getFullYear() + 1; document.write(year);` If I run what you have above it gives *me* `Wed Dec 31 1023 19:03:58 GMT-0456 (Eastern Standard Time)` instead of `1024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`. Honestly, I'd look for a date library to handle it for you, or just parse strings as text for storing in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It can get even more ambiguous. In genealogy (and ancient king history) we have many dates that are only years, but also approximations. Born about 1740 or ranges where we see someone living in 1725 and not in 1735. So the GEDCOM standard uses modifiers for before, after, between and about.

I manage this by using strings for dates in the format CCYYMMDD and a separate field in which you have <, >,-, c where the - (between) is followed by a second date. I then have a series of functions to decode, translate, add, sub, etc. these dates. You also need a function that pads in 0's to dates like 19670207. Translations involve conversions between formats; GEDCOM require DD MM CCYY (2 Feb 1735 or 1735 or Feb 1735). In displays, I use the math unicode symbol ≬ (≬) to indicate between: 1725≬1735. The format CCYYMMDD sorts appropriately as a string.

We have the same problem in Medicine, my profession. "I had chickenpox when I was about 5 years old."

Ambiguity is reality. We need to accomodate it and not force it into a rigid data framework. SQL Server is not a good solution for dates in these scenarios.